I want extraction of PDF to Tiffs in 300 DPI vertical and horizontal resolution and compression + CCITT T1.6
Here is the code:
import os
from PIL import Image
import fitz

def pdf_to_tiffs(pdf_path, output_folder):
    # Check if the output folder exists, and create it if it doesn't
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # Open the PDF file
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)

    # Determine the number of digits needed for numbering the pages
    num_pages = len(pdf_document)
    num_digits = len(str(num_pages))

    # Convert each page to TIFF with the desired settings
    for i in range(1, num_pages + 1):
        page = pdf_document[i - 1]  # Adjust index to start from 0
        pix = page.get_pixmap()
        # Convert pixmap to Pillow Image
        img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)

        # Set DPI (dots per inch)
        img_info = img.info
        img_info['dpi'] = (300, 300)

        # Generate filename with leading zeros based on the maximum number of pages
        filename = f"page_{str(i).zfill(num_digits)}.tif"

        # Save image with CCITT T.6 compression
        tiff_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
        img.save(tiff_path, compression='tiff_ccitt', dpi=(300, 300))

    pdf_document.close()

# Example usage
pdf_to_tiffs("C:\\Users\\ftp\\flask\\output\\90000026.pdf", "C:\\Users\\ftp\\flask\\output")

Extraction of Tiffs is perfect but I am unable to do compression CCITT T1.6 and vertical and horizontal 300 DPI.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How do you know you're unable to do the desired compression and dpi? Is there an error?

Hi @MarkSetchell  its like when I run this  I am unable to open generated Tiffs  and moreover  there is no change in compression and dpi .

Python dependencies usually include GhostScript in applications like Pillow.
So it is simply a one line program
gs -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -oAnswer.tiff question.pdf


If you want single images rather than a T6 file then transmit as single pages. No need to calculate pages, as it is done automatically for as many as available. Unless you over-ride the first and last with other switches (Read the Docs)
bin\gs -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -oAnswer%4d.tiff question.pdf


Results
78,588 Answer.tiff
78,588 bytes 1 File(s)

55,828 Answer0001.tiff
22,768 Answer0002.tiff
78,596 bytes 2 File(s)

NOTE windows users will need to replace gs with gswin32c or gswin64c.exe according to system.
Also You can ask gs to output page data for example.
bin\gswin32c -q -dPDFINFO question.pdf -o 2>_mytemp$&type _mytemp$|find "has"&del _mytemp$

will respond for above example a tabbed line         File has 2 pages
